# access audio and video in Firefox single browser page

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, html5-canvas

In my project requirement is :
registration form  have

1) Record button for record voice then stop

2) snap the image from web camera

i have done some functionalities for above 
using below plugins :
for audio plugin is : [AUDIO-PLUGIN](http://www.webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html)
for video image snap :

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
// Grab elements, create settings, etc.
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    video = document.getElementById("video"),
    videoObj = { "video": true },
    errBack = function(error) {
        console.log("Video capture error: ", error.code); 

    };

// Put video listeners into place
if(navigator.getUserMedia) { // Standard
    navigator.getUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream) {
        video.src = stream;
        video.play();
    }, errBack);
} else if(navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream){
        video.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
        video.play();
    }, errBack);
}
else if(navigator.mozGetUserMedia) { // Firefox-prefixed
    navigator.mozGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream){
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        video.play();
    }, errBack);
}   
document.getElementById("snap").addEventListener("click", function() {
context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 313,350);
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
});
}, false);
```

i got two issues ,

1) Firefox accessing only one media (either video or audio ), but chrome asking video & audio permissions then accessed .

2) my client wants , when open register form then with out asking 
permission accept these video & audio, (like : https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/ :this AUDIO+VIDEO did not asked any browser permissions when page loading.)

please save my days... thanks in advance..

```js
function fileSelected() {
    var oFile = document.getElementById('image_file').files[0];
 //alert(oFile.size/1024)
 if(oFile.size/1024 <= 500){  
// oFile.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
    var oImage = document.getElementById('preview');
    var oReader = new FileReader();
  oReader.onload = function(e){
        oImage.src = e.target.result;
  var resultStr = oImage.src;
  var result = resultStr.split(",");  
 // alert(result[1])
  $('#imageData').val(result[1]);  
  };
  //alert($('#imageData').val())
  //console.log("From Upload : "+$('#imageData').val());
    oReader.readAsDataURL(oFile); 
 }else{
  alert(" Your Image Size "+oFile.size/1024+" KB Please Upload Less then 500 KB ")
 }
 
}
// Put event listeners into place
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
 // Grab elements, create settings, etc.
 var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
  context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
  video = document.getElementById("video"),
  videoObj = { "video": true },
  errBack = function(error) {
   console.log("Video capture error: ", error.code); 
   
  };

 // Put video listeners into place
 if(navigator.getUserMedia) { // Standard
  navigator.getUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream) {
   video.src = stream;
   video.play();
  }, errBack);
 } else if(navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
  navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream){
   video.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
   video.play();
  }, errBack);
 }
 else if(navigator.mozGetUserMedia) { // Firefox-prefixed
  navigator.mozGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream){
   video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
   video.play();
  }, errBack);
 }
 // Trigger photo take
document.getElementById("snap").addEventListener("click", function() {
 context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 313,350);
 
 
      // save canvas image as data url (png format by default)
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

      // set canvasImg image src to dataURL
      // so it can be saved as an image
      document.getElementById('preview').src = dataURL;
   var result = dataURL.split(",");
   $('#imageData').val(result[1]);
  // console.log("From snap : "+result[1]);

 
});
}, false);
```

```css
.browse-image {
 padding: 25px 15px 0px;
 text-align: center;
}
.browse-image input[type="file"] {
 display: inline !important;
    width: 41% !important;
    float: left;
}
.browse-image input[type=button] {
 display: inline;
 margin-left: 10px;
}
.browse-image span {
 font-size: 18px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
.browse-image-button::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.browse-image-button::before {
  content: 'Upload Photo';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 145px;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(19,137,173,1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(19,137,173,1) 0%, rgba(33,180,226,1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(19,137,173,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(33,180,226,1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(19,137,173,1) 0%, rgba(33,180,226,1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(19,137,173,1) 0%, rgba(33,180,226,1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(19,137,173,1) 0%, rgba(33,180,226,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(19,137,173,1) 0%, rgba(33,180,226,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1389ad', endColorstr='#21b4e2', GradientType=0 );
  border: 0px solid #999;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 15px 8px;
  outline: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 10pt;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.browse-image input[type=button] {
 width: 145px;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(19,137,173,1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(19,137,173,1) 0%, rgba(33,180,226,1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(19,137,173,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(33,180,226,1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(19,137,173,1) 0%, rgba(33,180,226,1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(19,137,173,1) 0%, rgba(33,180,226,1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(19,137,173,1) 0%, rgba(33,180,226,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(19,137,173,1) 0%, rgba(33,180,226,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1389ad', endColorstr='#21b4e2', GradientType=0 );
  border: 0px solid #999;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 15px 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 10pt;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.take-photo {
 padding: 5px 65px;
}
.take-photo p {
 font-size: 18px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.voice-buttons {
 padding: 25px 0 0 0;
}
.voice-buttons label {
 font-size: 40px;
 width: 34%;
 padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div>
<video id="video" width="313" height="350"></video>
<canvas id="canvas" width="313" height="350"></canvas>
<img id="preview" border="1" width="313" height="350" />
<div class="browse-image">
   <input type="file" class="browse-image-button" id="image_file" onchange="fileSelected()">
   <span>or</span><input type="button" value="take photo" id="snap"> 
  </div>
</div>
<div class="voice-buttons">
   <label>Record Voice</label>
   <img src="images/record.png" alt="" id="startrecord" onClick="startRecording()" style="opacity:1" />
   <img src="images/stop.png" alt="" id="stoprecord" onClick="stopRecording()" style="opacity:0.5" />
   <img src="images/play.png" alt="" id="playrecord" onClick="playrecording()" style="opacity:1" />
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: If you want access to video and andio, you should ask for video and audio directly  : in your video example set `videoObj = {video:true, audio:true};`. Obviously, for security reason, the user have to grant access for these devices, there is no way you can circumvent it. They can choose to always allow it (only on https servers in chrome) but you'll have to request it at least once. Imagine if any website could look at your camera and listen to what you say...

Comment: @Kaiido thanks, its worked in Firefox,1st issue solved.. :)